# How to add custom user snippets like VSCode

Tags: code-snippets, godot, godot4, godot3

I'm a fresh developer on Godot and trying to understand how to add custom user snippets into system like VSCode's user snippets.

What I'm trying to do is basicly saving a string with changable part (#------> $1) with a short name (cmt). Then when I type "cmt" in code side I just want to make Godot autocomplete the text with saved string and focus on $1 to allow me change there.

Is it possible to do something like this in Godot? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you trying to add a snipped to Visual Studio Code? If so, having that in the tags would have helped you better. On the other hand, I'm unaware of a snipped system in the Godot editor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've found a solution which is not the exact thing I wanted to do but still works for now. :)